# Bootable Qt-Linux Application

Tags: linux, qt, bootable

How to boot a linux kernel + dependencies and auto run a Qt application so the linux environment doesn't show up (only the Qt GUI is visible)?

on **x86** PCs

should be able to run from RAM (of course)

Comment: Starting an application when the OS boots is a user-level question, not a programming one. This would be better suited on Super User.

Comment: Do you mean autologin after boot, starting X, then the fullscreen application? What distribution?

Comment: yes, a minimal distro, but with mouse cursor etc

Comment: It looks like you want to build a linux kiosk appliance. Google for 'linux kiosk' or ask the question on SuperUser.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could look at how this guy did it:

http://www.embedded-bits.co.uk/2011/1-second-linux-boot-to-qt/

Comment: but that is for embedded - with no source

Comment: @umar, see the link again. I'll quote: "If you're interested in exactly what modification I made and a little more about the approach taken - you may be interested in these slides"

Comment: ok, some guidance - the system used is linux kernel 2.6, u-boot(loader) & buildroot. I think `buildroot` is the solution, as on its site: " using various CPU architectures (x86, ARM, MIPS, PowerPC, etc.)" and "Supports several hundreds of packages for userspace applications and libraries: ... Qt"

Answer (score 3):

You could start with a minimal linux distribution such as Ubuntu Server and install only X-Windows (without any Window Manager) on top of it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI

Then, start your Qt application by adding a call to it in the [.xinitrc](http://www.slackbook.org/html/x-window-system-xinitrc.html) initialization script.

Answer (score 1):

Might be helpfull [Linux Journal KDE Kiosk Mode](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7718)

Comment: I am considering the size increase caused by KDE

Comment: Doens't KDE use Qt? So you will need the same libs

Comment: well maybe excluding plasma desktop and other things will reduce the size. But I am considering `buildroot` which allows for additional LIBS

Answer (score 1):

Why not run x server without window manager and the running the application in full screen mode on that x server.

to start x server type startx 
and then you must run your application in fullscreen mode 
(your app must support this mode by argument switch like this)

./myapp --fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this, but try google for 'framebuffer'. It should allow you to run a single application with no need for X server.

Comment: Qt builds its GUI on top of X. Unless the OP is talking about a daemon of sorts written in Qt, I don't think a framebuffer will help.

Comment: Qt/Embedded actually uses the framebuffer instead of X: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Support_for_Embedded_Linux

Comment: I wanted to propose this as well, but couldn't find the licence