# BeagleBoard-XM - Video Player Device Design

Tags: qt4, beagleboard

i am working on a BeagleBoard-XM RevA. I am trying to make a video player software works like a consumer electronic device. I want it to load at startup full screen and disable desktop environment of Angstrom. I am using Linux kernel 2.6.32 and Qt4 for software UI design on BeagleBoard. Anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361491/bootable-qt-linux-application), it looks somewhat similar to yours.